# In Swift, is it possible to pre-populate values for an enum’s associated values at compile time?

Tags: enums, swift, definition

I’m refactoring some of the code in this [“Swift-Tac-Toe” tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkYpoRj-7hA).

My goal is to create a couple of enums to model the Tic-Tac-Toe board instead of relying on “magic number” Ints that correspond to game board squares.
I have one that corresponds to each tile with a raw Int value:

```
enum TileLocation:Int
{
    case TopLeft = 1,
         TopMiddle = 2,
         TopRight = 3,
         MiddleLeft = 4,
         Center = 5,
         MiddleRight = 6,
         BottomLeft = 7,
         BottomMiddle = 8,
         BottomRight = 9
}
```

I’d like to create an TileRow enum that represents the various 3 square rows (horizontal, vertical, diagonal) that represent a “3-in-a-row” victory condition. I’d like to have each row contain a tuple raw value consisting of the three corresponding TileLocations:

```
enum TileRow
{
    case HorizontalTop = ( TopLeft, TopMiddle, TopRight ),
         HorizontalMiddle = ( MiddleLeft, Center, MiddleRight ),
         HorizontalBottom = ( BottomLeft, BottomMiddle, BottomRight ),
         // etc.
}
```

This results in an error “Raw value for enum case must be a literal” So I next tried defining the enum using a tuple as it’s associated value:

```
enum TileRow
{
    case HorizontalTop( TileLocation , TileLocation, TileLocation )
    case HorizontalMiddle( TileLocation, TileLocation, TileLocation )
    case HorizontalBottom( TileLocation, TileLocation, TileLocation )
    case VerticalLeft( TileLocation, TileLocation, TileLocation )
    case VerticalMiddle( TileLocation, TileLocation, TileLocation )
    case VerticalRight( TileLocation, TileLocation, TileLocation )
    case DiagonalLeftToRight( TileLocation, TileLocation, TileLocation )
    case DiagonalRightToLeft( TileLocation, TileLocation, TileLocation )
}
```

This doesn’t produce any errors, but since enums don’t have an init() method there’s no way to pre-populate the associated values with the constants I want. I could be overlooking something obvious here. I've read the [associated values documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_224) and didn't see any solutions. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Is there a better way to model this data with Swift?

Comment: The last implementation of TileRow doesn't do what you want; it provides static factory methods for making HorizontalTop etc., i.e. you can have multiple HorizontalTops (with nothing to prevent them having different locations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it is a pity you can't do this. You can in Java so I am used to coding like you show. The nearest that I can think of is:

```
enum TileLocation : Int {
    case TopLeft = 1,
        TopMiddle = 2,
        TopRight = 3,
        MiddleLeft = 4,
        Center = 5,
        MiddleRight = 6,
        BottomLeft = 7,
        BottomMiddle = 8,
        BottomRight = 9
    static let HorizontalTop = ( TopLeft, TopMiddle, TopRight ),
        HorizontalMiddle = ( MiddleLeft, Center, MiddleRight ),
        HorizontalBottom = ( BottomLeft, BottomMiddle, BottomRight )
        // etc.
}
```

The only downside is that in a switch statement you have to add a default case that throws a runtime exception, i.e. you loose the compile time checks.